# Segmentation Fault Character arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to code a simple TicTacToe game as a practice from C++ Programming book. This should be done without using pointers or vectors since i only finished the arrays chapter. I'm getting a segmentation fault when i try to run code. Here is my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void displayArray( char array[3][3] );



main ()
{
    char board[][3] =
    {
        {' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' '}
    };



    int p1;
    int p2;
    int j2;
    int j1;
    int i2;
    int i1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if( pow(-1,i) == 1 )
        {
            while ( board[i1][j1] != ' ')
            {
                cout << "Player 1 insert your indices\n";
                cin >> p1 ;
                 i1 = floor(p1%10);
                 j1 = p1%10;
            }
            board[i1][j1] = 'X';

        }
        else
        {
            while ( board[i1][j1] != ' ')
            {
                cout << "Player 2 insert your indices\n";
                cin >> p2 ;
                  i2 = floor(p2%10);
                  j2 = p2%10;
            }
            board[i1][j1] = 'O';
         }
    }
    displayArray( board );

}


void displayArray( char array[3][3] )
{
    cout << "Board :\n" ;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        cout << array[i][0] << '\t' << array[i][2] << '\t' << array[i]   [2] << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n' ;

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? what's the potential exception and at which line?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code and find out where the problem is

Comment: It just says "Segmentation fault" when i run the code. Compiles without errors or warnings.

Comment: Once you sort out the unitialized variables mentioned by others, `p1%10` gives a value from 0-9, but you have a 2D 3x3 array, so a `p1` of 3 or more is probably not inside your data.

Comment: `i1` and `i2` are not initialised before the first time they are used as array indices.   That is undefined behaviour.  They do NOT start with a value of zero.  Beginner mistake.

Comment: Yes it was the initializing. Thanks for the fast replys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   while ( board[i1][j1] != ' ')
```

`i1` and `j1` are not initialized to begin with. So when you do `board[i1][j1]` you are potentially touching uncharted territories. This is called `Undefined behavior` in c++ and the runtime is free to do whatever it wants if your code does this. For most cases its a Segmentation Fault.

Also this part:

```
while ( board[i1][j1] != ' ')
   {
        cout << "Player 2 insert your indices\n";
        cin >> p2 ;
        i2 = floor(p2%10);
        j2 = p2%10;
   }
```

is an infinite loop. Did you mean to write `i2` and `j2` instead?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks a lot for a fast reply, i'm beginning the love this community:) and yeah i forgot the change variables for the while loop too much copy pasting:)

Comment: @ÇağlarSamaner If an answer solves your problem, you usually accept it. #SoReadyToHelp. :)